# Can Functional Reactive Programming (FRP) be emulated to any degree in an imperative language?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, functional-programming, frp, imperative-programming

I understand that not every component of Functional Reactive Programming (FRP) may be implemented in most imperative languages purely as a result of how the language has been devised.

However, is it possible to use, say, events in C# to achieve a similar effect where a change in some input value cascades to update various objects? Or have I answered my question and there's really nothing else that could be done beyond variations of the "Observer" pattern? What about in other imperative languages besides C# (which I'm only mentioning here out of familiarity)?

Comment: Meet the [Reactive Extensions (Rx)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx) for .NET.

Comment: On the contrary, having imperative capabilities facilitates the implementation of FRP -- but there is lesser need for FRP in imperative object-oriented setting where things are already changing with time.

Comment: I'll add, have a look at FRP in Scala, which uses imperative features unabashedly.

Answer (score 1):

Reactive programming is not specific to functional languages, just like functional programming is not specific to purely FP languages. Python, D, C#, and many other structural/OOP languages allow functional style code to various extents, with many other languages having FP libraries.

If you google around, you'll find reactive libraries for a lot of languages.

Comment: OP asks specifically for FRP though, not just RP.

Comment: @Bergi That hardly makes a difference. FRP is just RP done using FP-styled code.

Comment: Not exactly. The RP library has a completely different style, as you can't really push events anywhere.

Comment: Isn't that an implementation specific detail, pretty much?

Comment: Nah, it's a design decision. And influences the design of your application code as much.